# Is there a Pandas/Numpy implementation of the Monty Hall problem without looping?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is more of a curiosity exercise...

If you've not heard of the The Monty Hall problem, it's explained in this great [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Lb-6rxZxx0).

I simulated it in python using numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

num_games = 100000
options = np.arange(1, 4, 1)

stick_result = 0
switch_result = 0

for i in range(1, num_games + 1):
    winning_door = np.random.randint(1, 4)
    first_choice = np.random.randint(1, 4)

    if winning_door == first_choice:
        stick_success += 1

    # remove a door that isn't the winning_door or the first_choice 
    door_to_remove = np.random.choice(options[~np.isin(options, [winning_door, first_choice])])
    options_with_one_door_removed = options[~np.isin(options, door_to_remove)]

    # switch door to remaining option that isn't the first choice
    second_choice_after_switch = options_with_one_door_removed[~np.isin(options_with_one_door_removed, first_choice)]

    if winning_door == second_choice_after_switch:
        switch_result += 1
```

Is this possible to do without a for loop though? Here's what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to do the door switching.

```py
import numpy as np

num_games = 100000
options = np.arange(1, 4, 1)

winning_door = np.random.randint(1, 4, num_games)
first_choice = np.random.randint(1, 4, num_games)

stick_successes = (winning_door == first_choice).sum()

# remove a door that isn't the winning_door or the first_choice
door_to_remove = ???
options_with_one_door_removed = ???

# switch door to remaining option that isn't the first choice
second_choice_after_switch = ???

switch_successes = (winning_door == second_choice_after_switch).sum()
```

You have to determine which door the gameshow host removes from each instance of the game (each row of the `winning_door` & `first_choice` arrays) and then switch the `first_choice` to the other remaining door.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Replacing `np.isin(options, [winning_door, first_choice])` with `(option == winning_door) | (option == first_choice)` might help you on your way. `choice` doesn't vectorize though, so I think the overall answer is "no". Sure, you could pull some trick with `np.vectorize`, but that's basically just a loop, and is similar in speed.

Comment: Is this a sequential process?  Remember we really aren't removing loops; we are just moving them into compiled code.  But from the Python programmer's perspective the operation changes from sequential to parallel, all steps and 'decisions happening at once.

Comment: Thanks for the insights guys! I guess you're right that using indexing is still just looping too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest issue here is vectorizing `choice` with a mask. That could look something like:

```py
def take_masked_along_axis(arr, where, index, axis):
    """ Take the index'th non-masked element along each 1d slice along axis """
    assert where.dtype == bool
    assert index.shape[axis] == 1
    # np.searchsorted would be faster, but does not vectorize
    unmasked_index = (where.cumsum(axis=axis) > index).argmax(axis=axis)
    unmasked_index = np.expand_dims(unmasked_index, axis=axis)  # workaround for argmax having no keepdims
    return np.take_along_axis(arr, unmasked_index, axis=axis)


def random_choice_masked_along_axis(arr, where, axis):
    """ Like the above, but choose the indices via a uniform random number """
    assert where.dtype == bool
    index = np.random.sample(arr.shape[:axis] + (1,) + arr.shape[axis+1:]) * where.sum(axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    return take_masked_along_axis(arr, where, index, axis=axis)
```

Making the first part of your code something like

```py
options_broadcast = np.broadcast_to(options, (3, num_games))
removable = (options != options_broadcast) & (options != options_broadcast)
door_to_remove = random_choice_masked_along_axis(options_broadcast, where=removable, axis=0)
```